# Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, cucumber, build.gradle

I try to run this gradle task

```
task runCucumber(type: JavaExec) {
    main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
    args += ['-f', 'html:build/reports/cucumber/', '-f', 'json:build/reports/cucumber/report.json', '--glue', 'com.waze.testing.cucumber', 'src/main/resources/features'
             , '--tags', '~@ignore', '--tags', '~@preRelease', '--tags', '@advil']
    systemProperties['http.keepAlive'] = 'false'
    systemProperties['http.maxRedirects'] = '20'
    ignoreExitValue = true
}
```

and get this error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main`

why is that? I can find it in the included cucumber jar.

**Edit**

I already have this task that runs successfully:

```
mainClassName = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"

    run {
        args += ['-f', 'html:build/reports/cucumber/', '-f', 'json:build/reports/cucumber/report.json', '--glue', 'com.waze.testing.cucumber', 'src/main/resources/features'
                 , '--tags', '~@ignore', '--tags', '~@preRelease']
        systemProperties['http.keepAlive'] = 'false'
        systemProperties['http.maxRedirects'] = '20'
    }
```

Comment: You need to add cucumber jar to `runCucumber` task classpath, via a `classpath` property.

Comment: but how come the "run" taks runs without classpath?

Comment: Don't understand. It has a classpath but you didn't pass the cucumber jar to that classpath.

Comment: so how come it works?
can you please write the syntax you mean? `runCucumber{
    classpath jarName
}`

Comment: See ma answer, if it solves the problem please accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script works in terms of proper configuration but fails since there are now features/test to check.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    cucumber
}

dependencies {
    cucumber 'info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.2'
}

task runCucumber(type: JavaExec) {
    main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
    args += ['-f', 'html:build/reports/cucumber/', '-f', 'json:build/reports/cucumber/report.json', '--glue', 'com.waze.testing.cucumber', 'src/main/resources/features'
             , '--tags', '~@ignore', '--tags', '~@preRelease', '--tags', '@advil']
    systemProperties['http.keepAlive'] = 'false'
    systemProperties['http.maxRedirects'] = '20'
    ignoreExitValue = true
    classpath = configurations.cucumber
}
```

This is how `JavaExec` classpath should be modified.

Comment: who filles `configurations {
    cucumber
}` and how does it determine the value?

Comment: This a different question (about gradle internals). It was defined by me and such custom configurations can be defined in gradle. I've added it to have a well defined cucumber dependencies.

Comment: it runs, **but** a) I get error of missing steps (even though they are implemented) `23:51:46.359 [QUIET] [system.out] You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:
23:51:46.360 [QUIET] [system.out] @Given("^There exists an admin logged in client$")
23:51:46.361 [QUIET] [system.out] public void there_exists_an_admin_logged_in_client() throws Throwable {
23:51:46.361 [QUIET] [system.out]     // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
23:51:46.362 [QUIET] [system.out]     throw new PendingException();
23:51:46.362 [QUIET] [system.out] }`

Comment: also the task finishes after few seconds. my test don't really run. `23:51:46.459 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection] thread 15: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Success
11:51:46 PM: External task execution finished 'runCucumber'.` even though execution usually takes more then 10 mins

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know your project internals and configuration. Initial question was about missing class which as far as I see is answered. If so please accept and post new questions in a separate thread.

Comment: @Opal Hi, How can we achieve the same in java class having main method or via a runner class of cucumber? I am trying a lot but not able to hack the issue. I am using these :   String[] argv = new String[]{"-g", "com/projecnamebdd/stepdefinition/",
                "src/main/resources/features/Regression/CheckingEndPointsInDealFlow.feature",
                "-t", "not @wip", "-t", "not @Multitenancy"};                  
                  Main.main(argv); //This method of cucumber is giving the error no file or directory found.