# Error running cucumber in eclipse- Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main

Tags: eclipse, maven, cucumber, feature-file

I'm trying to run a maven project using Oxygen.1 a release. I have the cucumber plugin installed. But when I run the default feature file, I'm getting an error `Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main`

Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794397/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-cucumber-api-cli-main)

Comment: @OhadR, seems to be the same root cause but within a Gradle project whereas this is in a Maven project.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Cucumber, but I guess you need to add it as a dependency to your Maven `pom.xml` as described in the [Cucumber JVM documentation](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm#java).

The Eclipse plugin adds syntax highlighting, content assists and other IDE related convenience. But you still need to tell the JVM where to find the Cucumber classes and in a Maven project this is defined by the dependencies in `pom.xml`.

You may rise a feature request at the [Cucumber-Eclipse issue tracker](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-eclipse/issues) to extend the plugin to allow adding the dependency to Maven projects automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Add these dependencies to the pom.xml and the issue gets resolved. I was trying with the latest versions so was facing this problem. When I changed the version then it worked for me.

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Hello. Please, the next time add the explanation outside of the code. It makes it more readable.